# Mutating variables inside a function - is it abuse?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I want to know what the best practices are before I go to my colleagues for a code review.

I know that the following code works. My question is whether relying on closure this way is generally accepted in JavaScript or if there's something problematic here that I'm missing? Thanks

EDIT: updated the snippet to more clearly show what I'm trying to achieve (cleaner, more readable code)

```
// All this is happening inside a function. Declared vars are not global.

var x, y, z;        // lots of variables to declare (to use in closures)
setupVars(true);    // lots of variables to setup
useVars();          // lots of variables to use

function setupVars(condition) {
    if(condition){
        x = 1;
        y = 2;
        z = 3;
    } else {
        x = 4;
        y = 5;
        z = 6;
    }
};

function useVars(){
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    console.log(z);
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting on: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for your interest.
Yes, this snippet was the most boiled down example of what I'm really doing and turned out to be trivial.
I have updated to my question to be more clear.

Comment: In general, excess use of global variables tends to be poor programming style, but there are appropriate times for them. If you use them, it's normal to update them in functions.

Comment: @Barmar The variables are not global in the sense that they sit on the window object. All this code is happening inside another function. I just want this part to be readable and without too many if statements.

Comment: thanks for updating the question. This should pass your code review unless there is a hard-stop on use of Globals. Your organization's coding style guide should tell you that. The alternative is the create a closure around all of this using an ES6 module or IIFE.

Comment: The philosophy is the same -- the distinction is between variables declared outside all the functions and parameters.

Comment: And again...more important and relavent information trickles out into the comments. I'm out.

Comment: @RandyCasburn The question is off-topic, so answers are not appropriate.

Comment: @Barmar - that was NOT directed at you! Purely at the OP. The OP started with a silly snippet, edited for more detail, then discloses this is actually inside a function (in a comment), what's next? It is a constructor function inside and IIFE inside a ES6 module? The question is not only off-topic, it is too-broad - the catch all for the unanswerable. Rant over.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm asking about best practices re: modifying variables in scoped functions. I am not interested in nor mention global variables... Snippets are supposed to be simplified. You mentioned global, so I answered you. Otherwise it is not relevant.

Comment: if a variable is in a scope, it's in a scope. Making things modular is fine, but don't overthink things. I would use `let` instead of `var` to be syntactically correct and to avoid scope osmosis in a potential for loop. There *are* better ways to do whatever it is you're doing, I'm sure. This seems very explicit and I assume it could be trimmed up much more succinctly for whatever use case.

Answer (score 0):

Using variables with same names as the global ones, inside a function, is not a good coding practice. In the above code, you should consider renaming x inside the function.

Otherwise, if the function is as simple as the one shown above, you could just do something like this

```
function modify(value){
    return modified_value;
}
```

Comment: This would become quite cumbersome for initializing lots of variables, if you had to use `var x = initialize_x(true); var y = initialize_y(true); ...`